# Xcode 6.2 - Expected type after 'as'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-6.2

First time seeing this error, can't i put '!' after 'as' in swift?
Or just bug after updating my Xcode to 6.2?

```
let url = notification.userInfo![CallbackNotification.optionsURLKey] as! NSURL
```

It shows error : 
Expected type after 'as'

P.S: You can try download OAuthSwift from github to test this error.
https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste relevant code instead of images

Comment: Updated my question, sorry..i am newbie

Comment: The solution for me was downgrading some dependencies to remove the '!'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `as!` notation was not introduced until Xcode 6.3. You have Xcode 6.2, so you have to say simple `as`. Xcode 6.2 does not understand your `as!`; that is the cause of the compiler error you are getting.

(Note that if you take those `!` away, then when you eventually switch to Xcode 6.3 you have will have to bring them all back again! It really is best *not* to change Xcode versions backwards and forwards like this. If your code was written originally with Xcode 6.3, you should *stay* with Xcode 6.3. The only problem is that in that case you cannot submit an app to the App Store until it goes final; right now it is still in beta.)

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to add ! to as to unwrap your optional variable in XCode 6.2

Comment: I using just downloading it from github to ready to import to my project. Should i remove them manually? It show nearly 50++ error inside it.

Comment: If you need to work in Xcode 6.2 your only choice is to remove them. Since `as!` is not a valid combination in Swift 1.1 (the actual Swift version that is shipped with Xcode 6.2), you can mass replace it with `as`

Comment: Excuse-me, it's Xcode 6.3 that uses Swift 1.2. In Swift 1.2, you have 2 possibilities to use as with or without !. Swift 1.2 separate the use of ! https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/